# Client Certificate authentication in Java

Tags: java, ssl, smartcard, pkcs#11

I need to login to a website using a smart card. I can successfully obtain the keystore from the smart card, containing user's certificate and a non-exportable private key (it's a regular PrivateKey object, but the "getEncoded" method returns null).

This site: https://pst.giustizia.it/PST/authentication/it/pst_ar.wp
has a login link which changes everytime you visit. So, as a user would do, I do the same in my Java app: I visit the page once to obtain that link, and then I perform the SSL Authentication on that link (Kinda like simulating visiting the page and clicking on that link).

This is the code I use:

```
public class SSLAuth
{
    private static String LOGIN_PAGE = "https://pst.giustizia.it/PST/authentication/it/pst_ar.wp";
    private static String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0";

    private TrustStrategy trustStrategy = new TrustStrategy()
    {
        public boolean isTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1) throws CertificateException
        {
            // Temporary work-around. I already know how to fix this
            return true;
        }
    };

    public String authenticate(String pin) throws Exception
    {
        // Request KeyStore from smart card
        KeyStore keyStore = Utility.digitalSigner.loadKeyStorePKCS11();
        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContexts.custom().useProtocol("TLSv1.2").loadTrustMaterial(keyStore, trustStrategy).build();

        // Get login token first
        String loginToken = null;
        {
            Document document = Jsoup.connect(LOGIN_PAGE).ignoreContentType(true).userAgent(USER_AGENT).timeout(10000).followRedirects(true).get();
            Elements link = document.select("div > fieldset > p > a");
            loginToken = link.get(0).attr("abs:href");
        }

        // Try to authenticate
        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setUserAgent(USER_AGENT).setSSLContext(sslContext).build();
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(new HttpGet(loginToken));
        if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != HttpStatus.SC_OK)
            return null;

        return response.toString();
    }
}
```

I need only to authenticate the first time, because once logged in, the website checks only a cookie named "JSESSIONID" and client's User Agent string. I have already tested this. Once you have these two valid parameters, you can visit the page even from another browser.

Anyway, the "loadKeyStorePKCS11" method gives you the keystore mentioned above, which contains the certification chain (99%, maybe 100% are only one certificate, because I tried 26 different smart cards, and they have only one certificate: the user's one), and a non-exportable private key.
I tried to look around the internet for solutions, but they are all about PKCS#12, which I don't need this.

I tried using different protocols (SSL and TLS) and different versions of it, but nothing!

Firefox can do smart card authentication, and I know for sure I'm missing something in the procedure! When I call the "execute" method on "httpClient" object, it gives me an exception: "handshake_failure" (SSLHandshakeException).

If I use "loadKeyMaterial" instead of "loadTrustMaterial", I get "unsupported_certificate".

I don't really know what I have to do at this point!
Do you have any advice?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: to see the reason for the failure add `-Djavax.net.debug=ssl:handshake` to your JVM. My guess is an untrusted root CA or a cipher mismatch.

Comment: [HERE](https://www.dropbox.com/s/94m10zrfhpy4zmb/ConsoleMessage.txt?dl=0)  you can find the entire Console log. The first 80 lines are debug messages from the smart card driver. The rest are from the handshake debug. Thanks in advance!

Comment: sorry dropbox is blocked by my proxy server.

Comment: [HERE](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxpZWDksTbV8T1hBd2VGNmNUY3M/view?usp=sharing) you can find the log on Google Drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for posting the log, I'll make this an answer since it's too much for a comment.

Short answer: the server is asking for a client certificate and you don't have one or are not configured to provide one that's acceptable.

Search in your log for this:

```
main, READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 11296
*** CertificateRequest
Cert Types: RSA, DSS
Cert Authorities:
```

This is the server asking you for a client certificate. What follows is a list of acceptable CAs. You must have a certificate in your keystore issued by one of those CAs and client certificates must be enabled for the session on the client side.

The next part of the log then says this:

```
*** ServerHelloDone
Warning: no suitable certificate found - continuing without client 
authentication
```

Unfortunately it seems you don't have a certificate acceptable to the server, or are not configured for client certificate mode and that's why it cuts you off and aborts the handshake.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your reply. [HERE](http://i.imgur.com/NXyhh68.jpg) you can find my certificate. It has been issued by a CA listed in the acceptable CAs. So I think the problem is something else... Do you have any advice?

Comment: I changed "loadTrustMaterial" to "loadKeyMaterial", and now I receive "unsupported_certificate" right after "*** CertificateVerify". What does this mean? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Export your certificate from your keystore to a file then use openssl to check it: `openssl x509 -in <certfile> -inform der -text -noout`. Check the signature and public key algorithms. Your log file states that the supported cert types are "RSA" and "DSS".

Comment: Also check that you've got the _JCE Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files_ installed on the client in case that's causing the problem with the installed certificate.

Comment: "Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption", "Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption", "Public-Key: (1024 bit)". For JCE, I tried "javax.crypto.Cipher.getMaxAllowedKeyLength("TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA")" and it returns Integer.MAX_VALUE. So I think JCE is actually installed! This is driving me crazy! :(

Comment: IT WORKS NOW! The handshake fails when the client certificate does not represents an enrolled lawyer. Otherwise, it works! Thanks!